# How to make a FB Page tab App visible to users who don't have FB account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on Facebook App which is a page tab,

I like to show that app visible to everyone, to the users those who don't have FB Account.

I tried,

```
  FB.Init
  {
   status:false   // previously it was true
  }
```

but didn't work out.

I also changed in this url `https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications`

App visibility to "public" and also changed Age restrictions, Country restrictions to "everyone", but didn't worked out.

The page is visible to everyone but on clicking the page tab, it redirects to the facebook login page.

Could someone tell me how to correct it?

Comment: I don’t think that this is even possible.

Comment: @CBroe I heard some guys said their app was visible to FB off users too..Is there any other way.?..the page is visible...why not the page tab on click?

Answer (score 2):

For me it wasn't anything in @Igy's answer, all my restrictions were off. In the Developers page, select your app from the App dropdown, select Status & Review, then toggle the first thing (Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?) to Yes.  That did it for me.

Comment: its already like that, but still redirecting to the login page..whats the probs..

Comment: This was EXACTLY the issue... so much searching to find this. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

All Facebook page tab apps are available to users who don't have a Facebook account / are not logged in unless one of the following is true:

- You've applied demographic restrictions to the page
- You've applied demographic restrictions to the app
- You've done something in your app's code which requires the user to be logged into Facebook, for example, if you auto-redirect people to the OAuth dialog

Here's an example: https://www.facebook.com/cocacola/app_1407266749487557
Screenshot when logged out:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dani, if you're being redirected, it might mean that your *page* - not the tab but the page itself - is not public. You can go to the page settings and edit the Page Visibility option.